# Trigger a multibranch pipeline on only gitlab merge requests

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci, multibranch-pipeline

I want to trigger a jenkins multi-branch pipeline based on merge requests in a *gitlab* repo. I checked only merge requests on `Integrations->JenkinsCI` in the *gitlab* project. But when I create a merge request to master, the pipeline is not getting triggered.

If push box is checked, the pipeline triggers as expected. I do not want to build the pipeline for every push.

Why isn't merge request trigger working? what am I doing wrong?
Is there any way to trigger *jenkins* pipeline only when a merge request is create/updated/merged?

[image: Gitlab JenkinsCI setting]

EDIT: I realized that in the [README](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#pipeline-multibranch-jobs) section of gitlab-plugin repo it is mentioned that merge request hooks are ignored as below.
"Due to this, the plugin just listens for GitLab Push Hooks for multibranch pipeline jobs; merge Request hooks are ignored."
Does this mean merge request hooks are not supported for multibranch pipeline? Does anyone have alternative suggestions to make "merge request only" trigger work?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148634/how-to-add-webhooks-in-gitlab-for-multibranch-pipeline-jenkins

Comment: @user_9090 The answer in the post you mentioned didn't work for me. I left a comment in the post.